# Web Hosting from Laptop for a small pack of users

Tags: web, tomcat, hosting

As part of my research I need to host a very small website that has CDN components. I want to host it from my laptop. I wanted to use Tomcat, but I having a very hard time making it run as no tutorials or so seem to help me. My website is html CSS based and there are not much of JavaScript used.

What means of free service can I use for hosting, some useful links or ideas would be very helpful.

I tried the Apache Tomcat 9.0 for hosting from my laptop but it is very complicated. As I cannot understand is it even possible to host a basic html css site?

I have no xml files.

I need to know what should be the credentials for Context Path (is it the folder or a specific file like index.html), what is the WAR or Directory path (the path of the index.html or the path to its parent folder?)

Is there any other credential I need to set or setup I need to add?